# Extracting the number of different elements of a specific column in a 2D list

Tags: python, list

I've got a 2D list of elements and I need to extract:

1. The number of different elements of a specific column
2. The names of those different elements from that specific column

```
mylist=[[1.0, u'1', u'COMPLETED', u' ARC',  30.0, 1.0, u'06/02/2014 09:20:18',u'2 CCW'],
      [1.0, u'1', u'COMPLETED', u' ARC ', 30.0, 1.0, u'04/02/2014 09:15:56',u'1 CW'],
      [1.0, u'1', u'COMPLETED', u' ARC ', 30.0, 1.0, u'07/02/2014 12:15:56',u'1 CW'],
      [1.0, u'1', u'COMPLETED', u' REP',  30.0, 1.0, u'06/02/2014 09:20:18',u'2 CCW'],
      [1.0, u'1', u'COMPLETED', u' REP',  30.0, 1.0, u'12/02/2014 09:20:18',u'1 CW'], 
      [1.0, u'1', u'COMPLETED', u' REP',  30.0, 1.0, u'12/02/2014 09:20:18',u'1 CW']]
```

In this list, I would like to check for instance column number 4 `list[3]`. The idea is extract the number of entries for `ARC` and `REP` and also the names `ARC` and `REP`. 
So far what I've managed to do is the following:

1. Transpose the "matrix" to obtain all the elements together

   ```
   newlist = zip(*mylist)[3]
   ```
2. loop over the different elements in `newlist`

I just wanted to know if there is a more efficient way of doing this

Comment: You have a lot of variable whitespace in that column; you may want to add a `str.strip()` call somewhere.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sure, that will help!

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name, by the way. You are masking the built-in type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these elements to a set:

```
newlist = [u[3].strip() for u in list]
s = set(newlist)
```

Then len(s) will be the number of unique elements, and the elements themselves are members of the set.

Doing it in one go is also allowed:

```
>>> s = set([u[3].strip() for u in list])
>>> s
set([u'REP', u'ARC'])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to loop over the values *anyway*, you may as well skip the `zip()` and do your processing in a simple loop:

```
unique = set()
all = []
for row in mylist:
    value = row[3].strip()
    unique.add(value)
    all.append(value)
```

or better still, do whatever you wanted to do with `value` right there in the loop rather than append to `all`. `unique` builds a set of unique values.

By using an explicit loop I also sneaked in a `str.strip()` call to normalise the column; you have a lot of variation in the amount of whitespace there. You may want to adjust how you build the list in the first place.